# VBA / Internet Explorer: Capture Resulting URL From OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I am automating some data collection using the Internet Explorer object in VBA, and have hit a wall trying to obtain a url resulting from a href onclick event.

The link is being "clicked" by the code below, which takes me to a Save As dialogue. I would instead just like to grab the resulting url generated by the onclick event. I can't pull this from the `<a>` tag as the href attribute points to javascript:void(0).

I know that IE itself knows the resulting url, as I can inspect this from the Downloads window if I manually download the resulting file, but is there a way to programmatically access and capture (in a string) the url to where IE is being directed by the onclick event being fired? Without actually having IE try to download the file itself?

```
Set Link = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each l In Link
    If l.innertext = "Excel" Then
       l.FireEvent ("onclick")
    Exit For
    End If
Next l
```

Comment: Maybe, but difficult to say without the related HTML.

Comment: Is the url public?

Comment: Not sure, What is the logic and code in OnClick event. It is hard to guess just with your above description. Your VBA code is not helpful for reproducing the issue. It is better if you post the HTML and JS code from that site which can reproduce the issue on our side. Than we can make a test with it to see how it is working in a normal condition and we can check whether it is possible to automate your requirement or not. If you want to automate the save file dialog than this link might be helpful to you. http://faidootdoot.blogspot.com/2015/04/excel-vba-automate-save-as-file-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps you?

```
Sub tst()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDOC As HTMLDocument
    Dim ieONC As IHTMLElement
    Dim ieONCs As IHTMLElementCollection

    ie.navigate "[your url]"
    ie.Visible = True
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Do: DoEvents: Loop While ie.Busy = True

    Set ieDOC = ie.document
    Set ieONCs = ieDOC.getElementsByClassName("[class]")

    For Each ieONC In ieONCs

        Debug.Print ieONC.onclick

    Next

End Sub
```